# Django+PostgreSQL: creating user with UserCreationForm saves it to auth_user table, but not to the table created for the User model

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models, django-views

I'm learning Django and now developing a simple food blog app for practice, using Django 4.1 and PostgreSQL. Since I'm not quite good yet at understanding how some concepts work in practice, I started with creating the basic structure (models, views, etc.) as per MDN Django Tutorial, and then went on adding other things based on various Youtube tutorials. I also created some users with Django Admin to see if everything works, and work it did... until I implemented user registration.

I successfully registered several users via registration form and could log in as anyone of them, view their profile page, etc., but found out they were not displayed anywhere in the users list. At the same time, I couldn't log in to any of the accounts I created previously with Django Admin.

Having searched for errors through the code of my 'recipeblog' app, I finally went to check the database I used. There, I found two different tables with different users: the first one named recipeblog_user, containing users  created with Django Admin, and the second one named auth_user, containing users created with registration form.

Thus I seem to have found the problem, but it got me stuck, for I don't know what to do with it. It seems to me that registration form should somehow be able to save new users to the table I defined first, but I can't yet see the way to implement it.

I found some suggestions to set AUTH_USER_MODEL in settings, but when I set
`AUTH_USER_MODEL = recipeblog.models.User` 
I only got

```
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.
```

I also tried to point the User model to use auth_user table, but when I set
`db_table = 'auth_user'` in User's Meta class,
I got another error, this time it was

```
ERRORS:
auth_user: (models.E028) db_table 'auth_user' is used by multiple models: recipeblog.User, auth.User.
```

I guess I can't simply merge two tables anyway, because they are not identical.

**Is there any way to make my app save newly registered users to the first table, recipeblog_user, and not to the auth_user? Am I missing something in the models or views? Any advice would be welcome.**

As for the code I have:

- in models.py

```
class User(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=25)
    ACTIVE = 'AC'
    BLOCKED = 'BL'
    status_choices = [
        (ACTIVE, 'Active'),
        (BLOCKED, 'Blocked')
    ]
    status = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=status_choices, default=ACTIVE)
    faves = models.TextField(default='', blank=True)
    registration_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, editable=False)
    update_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    password = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    email = models.EmailField()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['registration_date']
        db_table = 'auth_user'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('user-detail', args=[str(self.id)])
```

- in views.py:

```
class UserListView(ListView):
    model = User
    context_object_name = 'user_list'
    template_name = 'user-list.html'

class UserDetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = User
    template_name = 'user-detail.html'

def register_user(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RegisterUserForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data['username']
            password = form.cleaned_data['password1']
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            return redirect('login')
    else:
        form = RegisterUserForm
    return render(request, 'registration/register_user.html', {'form': form})
```

- in forms.py:

```
class RegisterUserForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=50)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your **User** class file instead of using a standard **User** class inheriting from
`models.User` do the following:

Import:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
```

Then replace `class User(models.Model):`

with  `class User(AbstractUser):` so it becomes

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    username = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=25)
    ACTIVE = 'AC'
    BLOCKED = 'BL'
    status_choices = [
        (ACTIVE, 'Active'),
        (BLOCKED, 'Blocked')
    ]
    status = models.CharField(max_length=2, 
                              choices=status_choices, 
                              default=ACTIVE)
    faves = models.TextField(default='', blank=True)
    registration_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, 
                                             editable=False)
    update_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    password = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    email = models.EmailField()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['registration_date']
        db_table = 'auth_user'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('user-detail', args=[str(self.id)])
```

Also make sure in your **settings.py** that `AUTH_USER_MODEL` is set to your new custom model inheriting from `AbstractUser`.

Once done, run your migrations and it should generate or update the table for you. It will use the same **Postgres** table as the original **Django** user, but the model it will use will be your custom model.

Comment: Alright, I see it now, thank you very much! I saw some suggestions about inheriting from AbstractUser, but didn't quite understand how it should help. Thanks for putting it all together!
I have one more question though: if I already have some migrations, won't this new one conflict with the old ones? I mean, can I simply run migration on top of what I already have, or should I better delete 'em and re-run migrations from scratch?

Comment: I would delete an re-run migrations once done updating code and **Django**'s **settings.py** file to make sure it's in sync. You can clean up your migrations but I'd run **makemigraitons** and then **migrate** to make sure the change took place on this specific app and model. Once your ```AUTH_USER_MODEL``` is set **Django** knows which model is the right one to use.